# Web audio api GainNode value what is the MaxValue

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

I looked in this page:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GainNode/gain
and I didn't find where they write what is the max value and the min value you can enter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The max value of the gain AudioParam is the [most-positive-single-float](https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#most-positive-single-float) value. That is a ridiculously high number.

https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#dom-gainnode-gain

You will most likely not need that. Since the `GainNode` does just multiply the signal any value above 1 is already amplifying it.